# Linux Process Spawn/Creation Trigger

Tags: linux, process, triggers, fork, spawn

I am attempting to programmatically track the processes a linux user is currently running. Is it possible to be notified when a user has fork-ed or exec-ed a new process, or is the only solution to perpetually poll the process list for new processes.

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [process events connector](http://lwn.net/Articles/157150/), which is based on a netlink interface.